# Is ITFoxTec.Identity.Saml2 library Support Signing of both SAML Responses and Assertions?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, okta, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using okta as my IDP, when i am trying to signed both response and assertion signatures at the same time i observed its not supporting. If ITFoxTec library supports signing of both SAML responses and assertions at the same time, i need some example or sample.

I want Signing of both SAML Responses and Assertions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If Okta is your IdP, Okta is the one signing the response and assertion. The ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 library support validating the signature on both the response and assertion at the same time.

Acting as the IdP, the ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 library can also sign both the response and assertion at the same time. Configured with the [Saml2Configuration.AuthnResponseSignType](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L72) property:

```
services.BindConfig<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration, "Saml2", (serviceProvider, saml2Configuration) =>
{
  ...
  AuthnResponseSignType = Saml2AuthnResponseSignTypes.SignAssertionAndResponse;
  ...

  return saml2Configuration;
});
```

[Configuration](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L32) from the TestWebAppCore sample.

Comment: [Error] [HBCS.Service.SAML.Middleware.ErrorHandlingMiddleware] [] Exception[3591a8461012420c851dc855826326c2] data[0, ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Cryptography.InvalidSignatureException]: "Signature is invalid." getting this exception.

Comment: Then the signature or hash algorithm is invalid (do not match the certificate).